# How may I stream live videos from my smartphone on my website?

Tags: php, html, css, jscript

I am trying to build a website where I would like to stream a live basketball match going on in my college. I'm certainly not interested in Ustream or vimeo type solutions.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Look into RTMP with NGINX. You could use any type of camera that connects to a PC and something like Open Broadcaster Software.
[link](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) I have to add though, I'm not a lawyer and I'm not sure if this would be legal.

Comment: Thanks Wicked, I'll look into it.